# Definition of sample

Tags: terminology, sample

Is a sample 1) just a subset of members of a population, or does a sample 2) include measurements of some property of members of the subset? The sources I am looking at give either definition 1) or 2).

Answer (score 0):

The individuals that constitute a population could themselves be thought of as scores, vectors of scores, or less mathematically defined objects (such as people, fruit flies, or schools) that may or may not have any number of scores associated with them. A sample is just a subset of those individuals, so the same ambiguity applies to the notion of samples.

This said, in the formalized world of mathematical statistics, the individuals in populations and samples are typically represented as scores or vectors of scores.